# Create dynamic id in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have my html and javascript code as below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
        #demo {
            border: 1px solid green;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 20px;
        }
    </style>
    <style>
        #demo1 {
            border: 1px solid green;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 20px;
        }
    </style>
<div id ="demo"></div>
<div id ="demo1"></div>
<script>
  var arr_args =  [["ab", "cd"], ["ef", "gh"]];
  var j, x = "";
  for (i=0; i<2; i++) {
    for (j=0; j< 2; j++) {
      x = x + arr_args[i][j] + "<br />"; 
     }
     if(i == 0) {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
     x="";
     }
     if(i==1) {
        document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = x;
    }
  }


</script>
</html>
```

now instead of me creating demo and demo1 id's. I need the code t do it dynamically. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The style for each `<div>` is identical so the CSS can be `div {...}` or better yet ditch `#id` all together and use `.class` instead: `.row {...}`. Currently `#id` is seldomly used because it's inflexible and inefficient. Use class selectors and gather all elements by class by using `document.querySelectorAll('.className')`

Answer (score 2):

You can use backticks as below to get the id as dynamic

```
document.getElementById(`demo${i == 0 ? '': i }`).innerHTML = x;
```

```js
var arr_args = [
  ["ab", "cd"],
  ["ef", "gh"]
];
var j, x = "";
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
    x = x + arr_args[i][j] + "<br />";
  }
  
  document.getElementById(`demo${i == 0 ? '': i }`).innerHTML = x;
  
  if (i == 0) {
    x = "";
  }
}
```

```css
#demo1 {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
}

#demo {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
<div id="demo1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelectorAll` to select all divs starting with "demo", then use the corresponding index to update.

```js
var arr_args = [
  ["ab", "cd"],
  ["ef", "gh"]
];
var j, x = "";
//Get all divs with an ID starting with demo
var divs = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=demo]");
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
    x = x + arr_args[i][j] + "<br />";
  }
  
  //Update the corresponding div
  divs[i].innerHTML = x;  
  
  if (i == 0) {
    x = "";
  }
}
```

```css
#demo1 {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
}

#demo {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
<div id="demo1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably really want to use a CSS class. `.className` in JavaScript.

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* js/external.js */
var doc, html, bod, nav, mobile, M, I, S, Q, special, unspecial; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', function(){
doc = document; html = doc.documentElement; bod = doc.body; nav = navigator;
mobile = nav.userAgent.match(/Mobi/i) ? true : false;
M = function(tag){
  return doc.createElement(tag);
}
I = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
S = function(selector, within){
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = function(selector, within){
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
special = function(str){
  return str.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/'/g, '&apos;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}
unspecial = function(str){
  return str.replace(/&amp;/g, '&').replace(/&apos;/g, "'").replace(/&quot;/g, '"').replace(/&lt;/g, '<').replace(/&gt;/g, '>');
}
var out = I('output'), arr =  [['ab', 'cd'], ['ef', 'gh'], ['ij', 'kl', 'mn', 'op'], ['qr', 'st'], ['uv', 'wx', 'yz']], outerDiv, innerDiv;
arr.forEach(function(a){
  outerDiv = M('div'); outerDiv.className = 'demo';
  a.forEach(function(v){
    // no need for `special` in this case but you may have special characters to escape
    innerDiv = M('div'); innerDiv.innerHTML = special(v); outerDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);
  });
  output.appendChild(outerDiv);
});
}); // end load
//]]>
```

```css
/* css/external.css */
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.demo{
  border: 1px solid green; padding: 10px; margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1' />
    <title>Test Template</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id='output'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
      [id^="demo"] {
            border: 1px solid green;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 20px;
        }
    </style>
    <div id="section"></div>
<script>
var arr_args =  [["ab", "cd"], ["ef", "gh"], ["ij", "kl"]];
      
  arr_args.forEach(myFunction);

function myFunction(item, index) {
document.getElementById("section").innerHTML += "<div id=demo" + index + ">" + item[0] + "<br>" + item[1] + "<div>"; 
}

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: One id per page.

Comment: As far as i know, he wants the code to be able to add the Ids dynamically to the divs so there is no need to create the divs manually, divs and their ids will be created automatically if the arr_args changes with this code, also to support more than 2 parameters, you only need to change item[0] + "<br>" + item[1] with item + "<br>" and if you want to remove (,) and add a new line between the items of each arguments, you can use str_replace in the Loop, I hope this helps

Comment: var val = i==0?'':i

Comment: var id = 'demo'+val;document.getelementByID(id);